# VIsual Studio 2013 C++ problems with reference qualifiers

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I found a lot of information in the internet about Reference qualifiers, and also I found that reference qualifiers are new to C++ 11, and are not implemented in all compilers yet. But I was unable to find any information for Visual Studio 2013, and reference qualifier. Can someone please help me with this matter ? Is it reference qualifiers in Visual Studio 2013, and should i perform any additional steps?

Also I have the following code:

```
    virtual AddOns* clone() const &
    {
        return new AddOns(*this);
    }

    virtual AddOns* clone() &&
    {
        return new AddOns(std::move(*this));
    }
```

Visual Studio 2013 returns this error on the following code:
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'

And I can not find any information how to correct it. Could some please help me?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Do you have the November CTP?  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/news/3271/microsoft-releases-visual-cpp-compiler-november-ctp-for-visu.aspx

Comment: I have installed Visual C++ Compiler November 2013 CTP, and now I can compile. However, I guess that because Visual Studio does not support reference qualifiers directly I still receive IntelliSense error.

Comment: @Mario, The CTP is a compiler update without a matching Intellisense update. The VS2015 preview should fix that, but it is only a preview...

Comment: @chris Thank you for the information :), however I still prefer to use VS 2013, and I will wait for the full version of VS 2015 before I transfer my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Visual Studio C++11 support table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable) clearly states that reference qualifiers have not been implemented yet, in a formal release. That includes Visual Studio 2013.

I have been unable to find confirmation in the release notes for the various Visual Studio "14" and 2015 previews that reference qualifiers are available in those previews (and therefore in the forthcoming Visual Studio 2015), though it wouldn't surprise me, given that [the November 2013 CTP ostensibly supports them](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/news/3271/microsoft-releases-visual-cpp-compiler-november-ctp-for-visu.aspx).

Furthermore, [a blog post from the Visual Studio team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx) also suggests that Visual Studio 2015 will support this feature.

Comment: [Here's a chart for the 2015 preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx).

Comment: @chris: Thanks. I don't understand why Microsoft can't get release notes right. Who wants to scan through a blog for accurate release details? Grr.

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-preview-vs.aspx#C++). Admittedly, it is hidden among tons of other VS components.

Comment: @chris: I'm not seeing it. Which passage are you referring to?

Comment: True, it's not exactly release notes. The bottom of the other page has a couple listed for CTP5. This is simply a more comprehensive list than the table and closer to release notes than a table on a blog. Best I could find with all of the information on one page, but it's not too bad if you ask me. I believe the reference specifiers are missing because they haven't changed since the November CTP and are not completely new to 2015.